# Why does implicit def require an import of implicitConversions but implicit val doesn't?

Tags: scala

I'm reading this [tutorial](http://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/tour/implicit-conversions.html), and at the bottom it states

> Because implicit conversions can have pitfalls if used indiscriminately the compiler warns when compiling the implicit conversion definition. To turn off the warnings take either of these actions: Import scala.language.implicitConversions into the scope of the implicit conversion definition...

The warning doesn't get thrown if you use an implicit val rather than an implicit def. Why is that?

In other words, if I do the following, I don't need the import:

```
implicit val int2str = (i: Int) => i.toString
```

But if I do the following, I do need the import:

```
implicit def int2str(i: Int) = i.toString
```

-----updated-----
Here's a toy example, that shows that the implicit val works:

```
case class CoolString(coolString: String)

class RichCoolString(rich: CoolString) {
  val hasCat: Boolean = rich.coolString.contains("cat")
}

object RichCoolString {
  implicit val coolStringToRichCoolString = (coolString: CoolString) => new 
RichCoolString(coolString)
}

scala> import RichCoolString._
import RichCoolString._

scala> CoolString("cool cats").hasCat
res0: Boolean = true
```

Comment: Implicit conversion is an `implicit` "automagically" applied to a value, which can be misleading. Typeclass is an implicit based of 0..n types.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most probably that's a bug, and there should be warning for both cases. At least I couldn't find exception in spec. Created https://github.com/scala/bug/issues/10392

Comment: Yup, it is even defined here, that `val` should also produce a warning: http://docs.scala-lang.org/sips/completed/modularizing-language-features.html (page 4 implicitConversion)

Comment: Thanks so much! I had been opting to use the val approach since it saved me an import, but now, knowing it's a bug, i'll revert back to using defs because they just straight read easier